# Getting path from current working directory not from root

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Hello everyone I am trying to get the path from the current working directory but I don't want the root path included with it in PHP or wordpress. For example I have a directory structure like this.

```
-C
--wamp64
--------www
-----------project
------------------Other directories
```

Now, what exactly I want is to get the path from project directory something like this.

```
-project
--Other directories
```

Currently with `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` I am getting.

> C:\wamp64\www\project\other_directories

But I want to get.

> \project\other_directories

And I wanted to make it dynamic so that it picks up the right path from which ever server I deploy this project.

I searhed alot but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I am not sure why you need it that way... dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) = dynamic

Comment: Not sure why you would need this either … But if `C:\wamp64\www` is configured as your document root, then it would be more than easy to check the length of that variable (in $_SERVER), and use string functions to cut as many characters off of the full path you got.

Comment: Sir I need this because I am making a backup plugin and this thing will help me restore the backedup file

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_global_server

Check above URL and use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

remove the filename from that and you will have the path relative to the document root.

Comment: Nope this didn't help